# using jquery/javascript for lookup on a csv file containing headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

My lookup file Kind of looks like this.

```
APP_FAMILY,APPLICATION
app_fam1,app_name1
app_fam1,app_name2
app_fam2,app_name3
app_fam2,app_name4
```

I have two select fields, like this:

this is where I want to show "distinct" APP_FAMILY column values

```
Select Application Family: <select id="app_family"></select>
```

this is where I want to show the APPLICATION column values corresponding to the APP_FAMILY selected

```
Select Application: <select id="app"></select>
```

Now I want both of these **select** tags to be populated by jquery or javacript from the lookup file. This is the constraint. Can anybody suggest how to proceed?

Comment: For what it's worth, jQuery is just a library written in JavaScript. Your answer will still be in JavaScript even if you use jQuery.

Comment: Thanks @Mike C, I know that. Still any solution is welcome :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use jQuery for my answer here.
First, you need to load the CSV file. Then you parse it, at the same time building the family select. Finally you need to listen for changes and update the app select.

```
$.ajax('/path/to/lookup.csv').done(function(data) {
  data = data.split('\n'); //replace with \r\n if you use Windows line endings
  data.shift(); //remove header

  var families = {},
      $family = $('#app_family'),
      $app= $('#app');
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (!data[i]) {
      continue; //skip empty lines
    }
    var fields = data[i].split(',');
    if (!families.hasOwnProperty(fields[0])) {
      families[fields[0]] = [];
      $family.append('<option value="' + fields[0] + '">' + fields[0] + '</option>');
    }
    families[fields[0]].push(fields[1]);
  }

  //next, fill in app select whenever the selected family changes
  function updateApp() {
    var family = families[$family.val()];
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < family.length; i++) {
      html += '<option value="' + family[i] + '">' + family[i] + '</option>';
    }
    $app.html(html)
  }
  updateApp();
  $family.change(updateApp);
})
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jscissr/cqsfuwkg/).